# Converting ppt to jpg

Tags: pdf, jpeg, libreoffice

libreoffice --outdir "output path" --convert-to pdf input path/*.ppt

When I execute this only the first slide is converted ,I want the whole file to be converted to .jpg files( n number of files).
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible -convert-to pdf path.ppt
```